# C# - Hide current form and show another one when a key is pressed

Tags: c#

How do I make it so that I can hide the current form and show another one when a certain key is pressed? Thats the code I have now

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) { this.Close(); } //press escape to quit
           if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)     //reload game
            {
```

Comment: Your comment says reload game, like restarting in the current form, not opening a new one. Which way do you want it?

Comment: I want it to have 3 options, currently I have 2 of them.

For the third one I want the user to be able to press F2 for example and it shows Form2 which will be a help screen of sorts

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching something along the line of this?

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) { 
           this.Close(); // Closing the initial form will close the application
       } //press escape to quit
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)     //reload game
       {
           Form1 f2 = new Form1();
           f2.Show();
       }
    }
```